# Does a professor need a student's permission to cite the student's unpublished essay in their own work?

Tags: ethics, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, coursework, intellectual-property

Would professors keep an undergrad student's essay to contribute to knowledge in a certain field? I mean keep for the purpose of citing and using it as a reference when conducting further research on the topic.

Or are they designed to just reiterate information already known just to prove that the student understands the material to qualify to pass a class?

Consider a scenario where the prof is covering course topics throughout the semester and then tells the students to write an essay (the typical introductory paragraph/thesis, body, conclusion, etc.). For example, a student writes about a certain topic in the field and the arguments used to defend that topic over an opposing claim against the original thesis. The student may present arguments that can can be a breakthrough in the field as to why a certain position on a topic is the best choice.

This could happen where the student has a background outside the classroom that contributed to the "original" discovery.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you are asking - advance who's knowledge? It's certainly true that an essay can advance a student's knowledge through writing, and that a professor can learn new things through reading student essays (I'm sure it is the best part of the otherwise terrible task of reading student essays), but they are generally not published to the public so they don't really "advance knowledge" in the general sense of research. If you clarify what aspect you would like to know about we could be more helpful.

Comment: @BrianDHall  I mean toward public knowledge in the academic field, such as a Phd would. I know it's a stretch to compare, but in the sense of creating a thesis in just an undergrad essay for say like a first or second year class that is a breakthrough in the research that hasn't been known yet.

Comment: Undergraduates do write and publish research papers.  It's rare, but it does happen.  But it doesn't usually happen from a _homework assignment_, which is what "essay" usually connotes, at least to me.  Can you clarify what you mean by "essay"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keep".

Comment: @JeffE I mean in the general sense where the prof is covering course topics throughout the semester and then tells the students to write an essay (the typical introductory paragraph/thesis, body, conclusion, etc.). For example, a student writes about a certain topic in the field and the arguments used to defend that topic over an opposing claim against the original thesis. The student may present arguments that can can be a breakthrough in the field as to why a certain position on a topic is the best choice.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I mean keep for the purpose of citing and using it as a reference when conducting further research on the topic. Or would they need permission from the student to do that?

Comment: It sounds like what you're *really* asking about is contributions to the state of knowledge in your field of interest, before becoming a graduate student.  Given that, you may find [this take on the subject](http://markburgess.org/blog_peer.html) to be of interest.

Comment: @Wildcard  I'm curious to know the rights of the student in the situation and how the professor can utilize the information even though it's not published. Mostly if the professor would need the permission of the student.

Comment: Your edited question is a much clearer question than the previous version. On the other hand, it's considered not very nice to change a question after it has already been answered, in a way that invalidates an existing answer, that someone put time and effort into. In that situation, it's usually better to leave the question as it was before, so the answer makes sense, and ask a new question in a new post.

Comment: Well if you look at the question body, the answer is still valid to what I'm asking.

Comment: I edited the question with an example (the student has an "outside" background), and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that undergraduate essays rarely contribute to the knowledge in a field, but there is nothing stopping them.

There is no rule that you have to hold a PhD to contribute.  You can be a graduate student, an undergraduate, or completely unaffiliated with a university and contribute.

Comment: I guess the prof would need the student's permission to utilize it to add to their own research? Would it be considered a part of the student's intellectual property?

Comment: @JPhills That is a tricky issue.  Of course, it would be considered a part of the student's intellectual property.  If it really advances the field, then the prof should encourage the student to publish it in a suitable medium.  Once published, the prof should cite it as appropriate.  If the student declines, then the prof can still cite but due to FERPA the cite might look like [unpublished essay from unnamed student].

Comment: would you think the prof would need permission from the student to hang on to it for however long in order to cite it? If it no longer exists anywhere to read, what would be the point of citing it?

Comment: The point of citing *anything* is to tell other people that the idea you're conveying is not your own.

Comment: @JPhills the prof would have no proof that he did not just make the student essay up, but s/he should not be claiming credit for ideas that are not his/her own.

Comment: @JPhilis imagine in a homework assignment, a student proves N=NP (or N!=NP) which would be a major advance in computer science.  The prof should encourage the student to publish this proof.  However, if the student refuses, the prof should publish an article heavily citing unnamed student's unpublished essay.  The field would advance.

Comment: @JPhills for an example of this look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#History

Comment: @emory wouldn't the essay need to exist in some form of readable format if you want to cite it? If the student doesn't want to publish it, would the prof need the student's permission to cite it?

Comment: @JPhills are all of Archimedes cited works extant? Does anyone have his permission to cite?

Comment: @emory but that's famous work one would call published a.k.a. accessible to the public. A student's essay is considered private intellectual property I would assume. And I would assume the prof wouldn't have the right to acknowledge it in the academic world and/or hang on to it for academic research purposes if the student doesn't wish for it. The prof could then steal it and abolish all proof of the essay existing in the class if the class is over for the year cycle and use the student's ideas for his own if he really wanted to.

Comment: @JPhills if the student did not want to share his/her ground breaking essay with the world, then it is his/her right not to.  The student's expression of ideas are protected, the student's ideas are not.  If the student does not want to share his/her ground breaking ideas with the world there are 2 options: (1) do not submit the essay to the prof, (2) have the prof sign a NDA before submitting the essay.

Comment: @JPhills I have taught classes and I have never read anything that was even close to worth stealing.  This is an extremely rare problem.

Comment: @emory what do you mean by the expressions are protected but the ideas are not?

Comment: @JPhills if you prove to me in essay form that P=NP, I am not obligated to forget it.  I am not obligated to not make use of the knowledge.

Comment: @emory so if the professor hands the student's essay back and the student shreds it, the prof can technically say the ideas are his own since there won't be any copies of the essay since it's unpublished. This goes back to my question of what's the point of citing when a copy of the essay doesn't exist? Which goes back to my question of whether or not the prof would keep it for citing purposes?

Comment: @JPhills if the student shreds the essay then there would be no proof of the prof's intellectual dishonesty (claiming credit for ideas that were not original to him/her).  Alternatively, the prof could just back date lecture notes and claim that the student received the idea in lecture.  We should assume that profs will act honorably.

Comment: Okay just needed some confirmation on that

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that your only protection from an unethical professor, whether you are an undergrad, grad student, or professional, is:

> Write a paper and submit it.

The ethical thing for the professor to do would be to say:

> The ideas you proposed in your term paper are very exciting and I believe have the potential to form the basis of a publishable article.  I would suggest that you apply to do a summer project with Prof. XX to develop your ideas further.  Also, Course YY, which will be offered in the spring by Prof. ZZ, would be quite helpful in terms of background knowledge / research techniques / writing mechanics (or whatever).  I hope you can fit it into your schedule.  Let me know how it goes!

And then s/he would return the term paper to you.

*My answer is based on a comment I once heard, urging a grad student to submit a paper quickly, that was in draft form, because a particular professor in the department had been observed going through someone's trash can.*

Answer (score 0):

That would be the "honorable" thing for the professor to do.

This is most likely to happen when the student has a helpful background outside the classroom. For instance, the student has a farm background, and designed a new farm implement for a mechanical engineering class.

It is "easy" for a professor to claim credit for teaching the student something "in class" that the student used, because of the professor's superior knowledge. The above example is one where the student is in the best position to defeat a professor's claim; that is, the student can challenge the professor to match his knowledge of farming.